# What is the term for referring to a brand in place of the product

Tags: terminology

Is there a name or term used to describe the phenomenon when a brand name becomes so ubiquitous that it is used in place of the product or related verbs?

Some common examples include:

- Google instead of search
- Xerox instead of copy
- Coke instead of cola
- BluTack instead of sticky tack

Comment: _Coke_ is neither brand name nor product, though it is one case where the brand and the product actually share a name (_Coca-Cola_ vs _The Coca-Cola Company_).

Comment: Good branding if your company name is synonymous with the verb/noun associated with the product?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet ”Coke” certainly is a brand. It’s a trademark of The Coca-Cola Company, and used as part of many of their product names (Diet Coke, Share a Coke). https://trademarks.justia.com/714/68/coke-71468708.html

Comment: Seems like it might tickle metonymy, too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These are *genericized trademarks*/*brands*.

See [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_genericized_trademarks) for a list and the following definition:

> English terms that originate from trademarks, brands and company names which have become genericized; that is, fallen into common usage in the target market's vernacular, even when referring to other competing brands.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_trademark) also known as a *generic trademark* or *proprietary eponym*.

Answer (score 1):

I myself haven't seen a special term for this kind of metonymic shift  but it is definitely an example of **semantic broadening**. cf.

[Horn 1984:](http://semantics.uchicago.edu/kennedy/classes/f09/semprag1/horn84.pdf) 35:

[image]

[Traugott and Dasher 2001:](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/regularity-in-semantic-change/F07CBB401A177975904C1E37BE0D9E07) 101

[image]

Sometimes this semantic change is referred to as an instance of eponymization. e.g. Popescu 2019:

[image]

Caveat: some semanticists use eponymization only for a semantic shift involving place names.

I haven't really seen the term "genericization" being used in linguistic research that much.

Answer (score 0):

I may be a day late and a dollar short, for which you have likely discovered the term you were seeking, but I believe the one you were looking for is a ***metonym***.

If this is too late to be helpful to you, perhaps it will find someone else who is searching in the present time.